# Nested Routes Using React Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have quite a few different links within my work application.  The newest one that I'm creating is a tech login route which will allow them to sign in and update their profiles.  I want to have the navbar stay on the main page while switching between the children routes without having to render it again, so I looked online and it looks like nested routes are the way to go for this.  The problem is that I can't nest `Route Children` inside a `Route Component`.  So I found that for `React Router` that you can just use the `Component` itself as a route.  My main question is, how do I set a path for the route of this component if I can't use the `Route Component`?

Here is what I have in my Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
            <Route path='/service' component={ServiceReport} />

            <Route exact path='/inventory' component={InventorySystem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/tracking' component={PartTracker} />
            <Route path='/inventory/build-assembly' component={BuildAssembly} />
            <Route path='/inventory/import-purchase-order' component={ImportPO} />
            <Route path='/inventory/update-item' component={UpdateItem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/create-item' component={CreateItem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/receive-items' component={ReceiveItem} />

            <TechPortalHome>
                <Route path='page1' component={Page1} />
                <Route path='page2' component={Page2} />
            </TechPortalHome>

        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

If I were to type in `mysite/anythingelse` it will render the `TechPortalHome Component` because there is no actual path for it.  Since none of the paths matched it will render that component instead.  I want to be able to go to `mysite/tech-home` and have it render this component instead, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: To make sure I understand your question, is `TechPortalHome` the navbar you mention at the top of your question? And your goal is that `TechPortalHome` renders for `/mysite/page1` and `mysite/page2`, but no other routes?

Comment: @taylorc93 I was able to figure out how to make it work.  I will edit this post tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this examples:

```
export default function NestingExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topics() {
  // The `path` lets us build <Route> paths that are
  // relative to the parent route, while the `url` lets
  // us build relative links.
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/components`}>Components</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
          <Topic />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic() {
  // The <Route> that rendered this component has a
  // path of `/topics/:topicId`. The `:topicId` portion
  // of the URL indicates a placeholder that we can
  // get from `useParams()`.
  let { topicId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)